# Регулярные выражения никнеймов разных сервисов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, faq

Давайте в этом вопросе составим список регулярных выражений никнеймов разных соц. сетей и сервисов.

Это необходимо при добавлении разных ссылок на аккаунты в профиле пользователя и не только.

Comment: для скайпа неверно. нужно где то так:

    /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]{5,31}$/


да и запятой я там не помню.

Comment: Почему так?

Comment: Исходное выражения для скайпа допускает имена, начинающиеся с цифры. А это не так.

Comment: Точно. Для инстаграма где найти? Точнее где прочитать о правильности никнейма?

Answer (score 12):

**FaceBook**
Для фейсбука выражение будет такое (если я правильно разобрался и ник это facebook.com/[nickname].
Выражение реализует правила:
- нельзя использовать только цифры
- можно A-Z 0-9 и точку
- длина не менее 5 символов не более 50
- нельзя точку в начале или конце, две точки подряд
PCRE:

```
^(?!.*\.\.)(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9.]{5,50}$
```

---

**Instagram**
 - можно A-Z 0-9 _ или точка
 - не более 30 символов

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,30}$
```

---

**Skype**
- можно A-Z 0-9 _ , . -
- начинается с латинского символа
- длина от 6 до 32 символов

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.,-]{5,31}$
```

Comment: Я ответ принимать не буду, сервисов много — тема актуальная.
Награжу тебя голосами за старание.

Comment: да ладно, 3000 у меня уже есть уважения. Другим отдайте.

Comment: @ReinRaus, поздно :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, благодарю, будет чем награждать достойных.

Comment: `(?<!\.)` - зачем его в такой форме? Можно же как с двумя точками `(?!.*\.$)` в начало.

Comment: Skype for Buseness (бывший Lync) имеет логины другого формата (ник@домен), но при этом частично совместим со скайпом.

Answer (score 6):

**ICQ**

```
^\d{3,20}$
```

**Кошельки WebMoney**

```
^(Z|R|B|U|E|G|X)\d{12}$
```